# angular2 reactive form | Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property stack of [object Object] which has only a getter

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement an angular2 reactive form, but I get a run time error when loading the component

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property stack of [object Object] which has only a getter`

This error isn't exactly clear, so I'm having a hard time figuring out what's going on. I'm following along with an [angular university article](http://blog.angular-university.io/introduction-to-angular-2-forms-template-driven-vs-model-driven/). I thought maybe there were breaking changes, so I checked the angular2 changelog but didn't find anything related to my issue with reactive forms.

Any help would be appreciated here. I'm going to keep poking around for a solution.

**addevent.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'addevent',
  templateUrl: 'addevent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['addevent.scss']
})
export class AddEvent {

  // vars
  private _addEventForm:FormGroup;
  private _eventTitle:FormControl;
  private _eventDescription:FormControl;

  constructor(private _addEventService:AddEventService,
              private _formBuilder:FormBuilder) {
    // init vars
    this. _eventTitle = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this._eventDescription = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this._addEventForm = _formBuilder.group({
      'eventTitle': this._eventTitle,
      'eventDescription': this._eventDescription
    });
  }

  private addEvent():void {
    console.log(this._addEventForm);
    //this._addEventService.addEvent();
  }

}
```

**addevent.component.html**

```html
<div class="h3 content-title">Add Event</div>

<form [formGroup]="_addEventForm" (ngSubmit)="addEvent()">
  <p>
    <label>Title</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="eventTitle">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Description</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="eventDescription">
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="_addEventForm.invalid">Submit</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

**dashboard.module.ts**

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [Dashboard, Navbar, Sidebar, Home, Profile, Events, AddEvent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpModule],
  providers: [ContentSwap, SidebarActivity, AuthService, FirebaseAuthService]
})
export class DashboardModule {}
```

Comment: I don't think you should be importing both the ReactiveFormsModule and the FormsModule.  I tried you code as posted and did not find the error.  See [this plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/buK2gqHNYwlUnDVPuqTm/).  So the error seems to come from code you didn't show.

Comment: The error is actually quite descriptive.  You have an object that it knows of only as  `[object Object]` (lets call it obj), you are trying to set a property `stack` (say by calling `obj.stack = something`, but you aren't allowed to because the `stack` property is read-only (has a getter, no setter).  The problem is that the assignment may occur anywhere (maybe not your code, but maybe caused by something you pass in to library code), so you need to look at the stack trace to see where it comes from.

Comment: @StevenLuke both modules are required, the error comes from having angular form directives.

Comment: @StevenLuke the error is non-descriptive as pertaining to angular form directives, and why the error occurs.

Comment: Re: first response - For both FormsModules - Bother the page you linked and my tests suggest that you need ReactiveFormsModule, but do not need FormsModule, at least for the code you posted.  Not sure if there is some other need for it.  Re: Second response - I think it comes down to where and who knows what - the error is describing exactly the problem, the root cause could be from elsewhere.  Luis Cazacu has probably got it right.

Comment: @StevenLuke you were right about the error stemming from another source, I was missing a provider in my module!

Answer (score 6):

I get the same error sometimes. Looks like a bug in the latest zonejs/angular.  To get your real error put a breakpoint on the stack from where this error is thrown. Your real error will be an input argument to the function it crashes.

If you need more details https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/427

Comment: that's interesting, I'll have to look into that more. Thanks for telling me about the break point, I'll try that out.

Comment: that thread got me to the bottom of the issue, I was missing a provider in my module!

Answer (score 1):

Following the thread for an issue on angular/zone.js, a [comment](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/427#issuecomment-245021947) pointed me in the direction of getting down to the real error.

`uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'configurable' on string 'Error: No provider for AddEventService!`

I was just missing a provider for a new service I created.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a chrome extension that was throwing the error, setting a break point at the point of failure on zone.js revealed the offending extension. I then grabbed the extension ID and disabled that extension in chrome and all was good.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I accidentally put two decorators on a `@ViewChild`, while using the `ngxs` library, which relies on immutability, like so:

```
  import { Select } from '@ngxs/store';

  // @Select(AppLoginAPIState.getAuthenticatedUser) // uncomment to produce the error
  @ViewChild('redirectCheckModal')
  redirectCheckModal: ModalComponent;
```